# JAVACV : Webcam capturing using javacv

Tags: opencv, webcam, javacv

Tried to capture from a webcam using the JAVACV library. But it throws an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.
Stack trace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
C:\Users\anooj\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp7955905460040\jniopencv_core.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1928)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:418)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:368)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:315)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:131)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:96)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:334)
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:91)
at com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber.start(OpenCVFrameGrabber.java:170)
at javaapplication16.JavaApplication16.captureframe(JavaApplication16.java:24)
at javaapplication16.JavaApplication16.main(JavaApplication16.java:38)
Java Result: 1
```

Our code is below:

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameGrabber;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvSaveImage;

public class JavaApplication16 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void captureframe()
    {
        OpenCVFrameGrabber grabber=new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
        try
        {
            grabber.start();
            IplImage img=grabber.grab();
            if(img!=null)
            {
                cvSaveImage("capture.jpg", img);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ae)
        {
            ae.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        captureframe();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link to solve the error you got [Link1](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/12/opencv-javacv-eclipse-project.html)

see this link for the program to capture the image from camera, save it in a JPG format and show it on a canvas [Link2](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.in/2011/12/javacv-capture-save-flip-show-live.html)

hope it solves your query.

Comment: Thnk u so much. Also I want to know how to record video from my webcam using Javacv. How can I implement it using  FrameRecorder.

Comment: showing
Aug 05, 2012 5:11:19 PM motiontest1.Motiontest1$RemindTask run
SEVERE: null
com.googlecode.javacv.FrameRecorder$Exception: cvWriteFrame(): Could not record frame
 at com.googlecode.javacv.OpenCVFrameRecorder.record(OpenCVFrameRecorder.java:90)

Answer (score 2):

- Make Sure you have installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable
  package and setup path variable correctly. Below link explains all
  the necessary steps
  http://opencvlover.blogspot.in/2012/04/javacv-setup-with-eclipse-on-windows-7.html
- Use VideoInputFrameGrabber instead of OpncvFrameGrabber as suggested
  in link below
  http://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/Windows7AndOpenCV#I_cannot_capture_from_my_Webcam_using_opencv_highgui_or_OpenCVFr

Comment: Thank u so much. 
Now webcam capturing is successful. I want to take a screenshot of any of the frame & to save it in any target. 
Is it possible to save an IplImage to a png file or jpg file ?

Comment: You can use cvSaveImage(String filename, IplImage img). You can specify desired format in filename itself. e.g cvSaveImage("myImg.png", img)

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the version of openCV and javaCV must match.
Download latest version openCV 2..46 http://opencv.org/downloads.html

and download the javacp https://code.google.com/p/javacv/downloads/list [Note: choose the  javacv-0.6-cppjars.zip   85.0 MB]

In this case you will not get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

My Code is running successfully.