# Detect Hand/Finger Gesture in javacv

Tags: javacv, gesture-recognition

I'm beginner in JavaCV. I want to take a snap based on hand gesture and process the image. how can i detect hand/finger gesture in javacv? what technique is to be used?

where can i get javacv documentation [help/tutuorials]?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation for javacv,but opencv does have..most of the method definitions are similar ..it would help.
To detect hand u need to capture the image.see this link [JAVACV : Webcam capturing using javacv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539230/javacv-wbcam-capturing-using-javacv) 
Then use CvThreshold to convert the image to binary. Use CvFindContour, to get a boundary around your detected shape.